# How to restrict a string length in html

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-length

I have a webpage in html which captures address first name and lastname of a person. On clicking submit button , in a text area , it will display address entered with first name and last name
Actually I have given 50 character restriction to text field. But if some one is giving a small address, the entire content is shifting to left. I want all the entries in correct alignmnet

For example if i have given 2 inputs,

1. fname-kiran,lname-bhal,adrress- Kiran Bhavan,Pune
   2.fname-nanditha,lname-das,adrress- NANDITHA,tc10/10,street 11,Pune

The output Iam getting

1. Please find the address of Kiran Bhavan, Pune of Kiran Bhal
2. Please find the address of NANDITHA,tc10/10,street 11,Pune of Nanditha Das

Both not in same alignment

The output I want is

[image]

Both fname,lname and address in same position for all.

**If the address is small, fill the remaining spaces with Blank**

Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function IV() {
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;          
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var address= document.getElementById("address").value;
        var result = 'Please find the address of' +address+'of                   '+fname' 
        '+lname
        document.getElementById('spanResult').textContent = result;
         
       }

     </script>


     </head>
       <header>
         <h1>SNA fname - IV</h1>
     </header>
     <body> 
     <table> 
       <form >
           <tbody> 
            <tr> 
                <td align="middle" colspan="2"> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td width="24%" style="width: 20%"> 
                   First name :
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <input id="fname" size="30" name="fname" />
                </td> 
                <td width="9%"> 
                </td> 
              </tr> 
              <tr> 
                <td style="width: 20%"> 
                    Last name: 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <input id="lname" size="30" name="lname" /> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
           <tr> 
                <td style="width: 20%"> 
                    Address: 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                    <input id="address" size="30" name="address" /> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
               
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
       </table> 
    
      </form >
      <button  onclick=

"IV()"  >IV</button> <br />
      <textarea id="spanResult" rows="10" cols="200"></textarea>    
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what went wrong with your code, when the results you get and what you want are the same on my screen. Also what does regex have to do with this?

Comment: Sorry for that .. Now only i noticed the spaces i have given in the question was not displaying. Please find the image I have attached.

Comment: In the first input, since adress size is less..upto 50 characters it is filled with blank..fname starts in correct position, not shifting to left

Comment: You didn't find any answer online?

Comment: Got some..not meeting my criteria